# SQL Server schema best practices

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, schema

I'm in the process of designing a new database for an application. I'd like to be mindful of the security from the start (which should be the norm!). Anyone got a link to a resource describing the best way to use schemas to implement good security?

By using schemas, I mean not just dumping everything under the default dbo schema. Surely there's a schema best practises out there? Can't find it if there is...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Security Enhancements in SQL Server 2005: Schema**
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/authorization_2005_p1.aspx

**SQL Server Best Practices: User-Defined Schemas**
http://blogs.msdn.com/buckwoody/archive/2009/06/18/sql-server-best-practices-user-defined-schemas.aspx

...And the obligatory MSDN reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx

Comment: Thanks Robert,

It's not quite what I was after, but these are the same links that I'm using to piece the require information together, so guess that it's the answer.